# HTMLPurifier - add name attribute to anchor tag

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

HTMLPurifier strips the `name` attribute from the `anchor` tag
Using the [documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) in the past, I've successfully created a new element "include".

But I can't get the code to also add the `name` attribute for the `anchor` tag. My preference is NOT to limit the `name` values. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
// custom tag for included files
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'include');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 16);
if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
    // this works for adding the include element
    $def->addElement('include', 'Block', 'Empty', 'Common', array('file*' => 'URI', 'height' => 'Text', 'width' => 'Text'));

  // This doesn't work - among the many things, I've tried...
  // 1) trying to get at least name ="target" to work
  // $def->addAttribute('a', 'name', 'Enum#target');
  // 2) trying to get any text to work
  // $def->addAttribute('a', 'name', 'text');
  // $def->addAttribute('a', 'name', new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Text());
}

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are two options. One is to define all elements and tags using `HTML.Allowed`. Simpler is to set `Attr.EnableID` which allows `id` and `name` attributes. Setting `Attr.IDPrefix` will help prevent name collisions. This works:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
// allow name and id attributes
$config->set('Attr.EnableID', true);
// prefix all id and names with user_
$config->set('Attr.IDPrefix', 'user_');

// custom tag 
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'include');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 2);
if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
    $def->addElement('include', 'Block', 'Empty', 'Common', array('file*' => 'URI', 'height' => 'Text', 'width' => 'Text'));
}

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set name attribute as true in Name.php, please check

> http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.Attr.Name.UseCDATA